# Bitcoind -walletnotify more than 6 confirmations?

Tags: transactions, bitcoind, confirmations

I've configured bitcoind -walletnotify to run php script when callback is triggered. It works fine, but only notify until 3 confirmations are received. My goal is to notify when 6 confirmations are received for that transaction. Is there a way to configure it to notify until 6 confirmations?

Answer (score 7):

The Bitcoin Core `-walletnotify` should only run at most twice for a typical transaction:

1. When the transaction enters the local node's [mempool](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-guide#memory-pool)
2. When a block arrives containing that transaction.

I haven't tested this, but it looks like the code may also send a notify if the transaction is conflicted, if it is no longer confirmed after a reorg, or when it is confirmed by a different block after a reorg.

But that means you should only be notified until 1 confirmation, not 3 as you say in your question.

There is no setting that lets you choose when you get notified.  However, you can build this feature for yourself using a `-blocknotify` command that calls one of the RPCs, such as [`listtransactions`](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#listtransactions).  Then you can check the confirmations field for each transaction and trigger an action if it's greater than or equal to 6.

You can alternatively use the [`listsinceblock` RPC](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#listsinceblock) to list all transactions in the wallet that aren't part of the fifth most recently confirmed block or an earlier block.  (That is, transactions that don't yet have six confirmations.)